# Exception after installing reddit: InvariantException: Redefining type 'CommentTreeStorageV2'?

Tags: python, reddit

I'm trying to install [reddit](https://github.com/reddit/reddit) engine. So was trying to use [install script](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/reddit-install-script-for-Ubuntu) for Ubuntu 12.04. The script completed successfully without any errors on my Ubuntu 12.04 x64.
But then i'm getting this error when trying to access installed instance:

`InvariantException: Redefining type 'CommentTreeStorageV2'?`

```
File '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/weberror/evalexception.py', line 431 in respond
  app_iter = self.application(environ, detect_start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 168 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 265 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 223 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 238 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 343 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 369 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, custom_start_response)
File '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/routes/middleware.py', line 130 in __call__
  response = self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 116 in __call__
  self.setup_app_env(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 380 in setup_app_env
  self.load_controllers()
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 392 in load_controllers
  controllers.load_controllers()
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/controllers/__init__.py', line 42 in load_controllers
  from listingcontroller import ListingController
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/controllers/listingcontroller.py', line 23 in 
  from oauth2 import OAuth2ResourceController, require_oauth2_scope
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/controllers/oauth2.py', line 30 in 
  from r2.lib.base import abort
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/lib/base.py', line 28 in 
  from r2.lib.template_helpers import get_domain
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/lib/template_helpers.py', line 23 in 
  from r2.models import *
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/models/__init__.py', line 26 in 
  from builder import *
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/models/builder.py', line 34 in 
  from r2.lib.comment_tree import moderator_messages, sr_conversation, conversation
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/lib/comment_tree.py', line 28 in 
  from r2.models.comment_tree import CommentTree
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/models/comment_tree.py', line 133 in 
  class CommentTreeStorageV2(CommentTreeStorageBase):
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/lib/db/tdb_cassandra.py', line 133 in __init__
  raise InvariantException("Redefining type %r?" % (cls._type_prefix))
InvariantException: Redefining type 'CommentTreeStorageV2'?
```

I have tried to populate database with test data using populatedb.populate(). And it also completed successfully, but same error when trying to access instance.
I have checked all configurations and cron jobs with the manual installation instruction and all looks fine for me..

What can be wrong and to what should i look at?